# How do I compose XDocument with the following layout?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create the following XML structure with XDocument:

```
<g id="9ucyw2OU0yEeZODj" ctype="x-html-p">
   <g id="ejY48F8jEWHSkq6F" ctype="x-html-span" xhtml:style="font-size: 17px;">
      Soy
      <g id="owSEx-Nil-3InZLk" ctype="x-html-strong">EL CLIENTE</g>
      . Bienvenido/a al portal de formación de Kasafy, una empresa con una red de agencias 
   </g>
</g>
```

I'm close but it's coming out like this:

```
<g id="9ucyw2OU0yEeZODj" ctype="x-html-p">
  <g id="ejY48F8jEWHSkq6F" ctype="x-html-span" xhtml:style="font-size: 17px;">Soy</g>
  <g id="owSEx-Nil-3InZLk" ctype="x-html-strong">EL CLIENTE</g>
  . Bienvenido/a al portal de formación de Kasafy, una empresa con una red de agencias
</g>
```

The second line (after Soy) is closing the tag too soon.  It shouldn't happen until after the last line (. Bienvenido/a al portal...)

Here is the code that I have that gets me to this point:
Note:

- sourceTranslated = "Soy"
- sourceTranslated2 = "EL CLIENTE"
- sourceTranslated3 = ". Bienvenido/a al portal de formación de Kasafy, una empresa con una red de agencias"

> XElement el = transUnitNode.Descendants("g").FirstOrDefault(l =>
> (string)l.Attribute("id") == parentID)
>
> if (el != null) { el.Add(new XElement("g", "", new XAttribute("id",
> xaID), new XAttribute("ctype", xaCType), sourceTranslated, new
> XAttribute(xhtml + "style", xaXhtml))); }
>
> if (el != null) { el.Add(new XElement("g", new XAttribute("id",
> firstNodeNextNodeFirstAttributeValue), new XAttribute("ctype",
> firstNodeNextNodeLastAttributeValue), sourceTranslated2)); }
>
> if (el != null) { el.Add(sourceTranslated3); }

The problem seems to be when I add sourceTranslated2.  It closes the tag for sourceTranslated.

Thoughts or suggestions on how to solve the tag  closing too soon?

**Possible Solution**
jdweng added a comment below that should work (haven't tested for my situation but will soon).
I tried the following - combine all XElements into one statement which seems to have done the trick:

> if (el != null) { el.Add(new XElement("g", "", new XAttribute("id",
> xaID), new XAttribute("ctype", xaCType), sourceTranslated, new
> XAttribute(xhtml + "style", xaXhtml), new XElement("g", new
> XAttribute("id", firstNodeNextNodeFirstAttributeValue), new
> XAttribute("ctype", firstNodeNextNodeLastAttributeValue),
> sourceTranslated2), sourceTranslated3)); }

Comment: You need an intemdiate variable since you are adding to Elements to the same parent.  So do something like this : Xelement firstNode = new XElement("g", "", new XAttribute("id", xaID), new XAttribute("ctype", xaCType), sourceTranslated, new XAttribute(xhtml + "style", xaXhtml)));

Comment: I'll give that a try, too - I found another solution as well.  Adding to my post with the solution I discovered.

Comment: There is only one solution, but more than one way of implimenting the solution.  You problem is you need to add two child elements to the same parent which is not possibile with your present code.